# Not able to install .ipa via iTunes after updating to iOS 9.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I used to create the ipa file from Xcode/Product/Archive and install it via iTunes. After updating the iPad to iOS 9.3.1, the app keeps showing "Installing" in iTunes and disappears the installing icon on iPad after loading but never completed. With the Build and run the current scheme option, this app can install on iPad.

I had already updated my Xcode to 7.3 and iTunes. Any solutions to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I think there is some issue in iOS 9.3.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578808/not-able-to-install-apps-after-update-ios-9-3-1

Comment: i didn't find any solution yet. i am also facing the same issue exactly what you are facing?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @karlml I used the below two options that I answered. Both are working. Cheers!

Comment: @zarli What do you mean both solutions...?  Is it not one answer basically use diawi ?

Comment: @karlml Second solution is as I mentioned that add device's UDID number in your developer account and use development team profile to export your .ipa. This ipa, you can install via itunes or OTA already.

Comment: @zarli That gives me the error:“In House distribution provisioning profiles for this account will be available two weeks after program activation”

Comment: @karlml It's their normal process. They calculate your account activation date two weeks after your payment. You can call to apple support phone number to try to activate your account asap. But not much so fast.

Comment: @zarli Thank you that worked

Comment: @karlml Happy to hear that

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I know we need the enterprise account for in house distributions.

Alternate solutions are using

1. Using third party's solution, I used https://www.diawi.com/. It works perfect.
2. Using your apple developer account, add your devices' UDID number and used development team profile to install. Only 100 devices are allowed.
   Good luck!